# Codeigniter unicode issue

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm a seasoned PHP developer, but fairly new to using Codeigniter. I'm having a very strang challenge I've never encountered before.
I've created an "assets" folder to put my css, js and images in. Within the js folder, I've created a "main.js". Initiallly this file saved and loaded in the page just fine.
However, after making changes to the file, it now keeps the initial state of the file (gives appearance of caching), but adds unicode chatacters to the bottom of the file.
I view the file itself on the server (vi), and the changes are there (no unicode). But when I load this file in the browser, directly or from the template (link src=""), it loads the initial state with unicode characters at the bottom.
See screen shot. I am at a loss. If I revert the file to it's initial state, the page loads without the unicode characters. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: it has nothing to do with CI  , most likely it has happened while editing file ... have you edited the file with unusual editor ? like windows notepad or any online editor .. why dont you just copy the codes in another file ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the editor - nothing unusual. Also, as mentioned, I've confirmed the contents of the js file are accurate with vi. Something with CI or apache is rendering the file unmodified but with unicode at the bottom.

Comment: UPDATE: I did a system update to CentOS and rebooted the machine. This seems to have reset the file to the new initial state. Meaning, my changes now work. However, if I make any further changes, the unicode just gets added at the bottom.

Comment: Anyone? I have to reboot my VM every time I make a change to a CSS or Javascript file. Whenever I change either of these files, it adds unicode to the bottom. So weird. I have similar VMs running CakePHP and Laravel, and have no problems with those. Just this VM with Codeigniter has the issue.

Comment: I found the problem. It's a bug with Vagrant. See here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html